# WooCommerce Email Customization

Tags: plugins

I need to edit the code in the woocommerce new order email to not show the price but I still need to have it show the product purchased and the number of products purchased. Currently there is a single line of code the pulls the whole table of products purchased and the prices.

```
echo $order->get_order_item_totals( false, true );
```

How to replace this line of code with something that will show only the products and number of products but not the price paid?

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering the output of that function to remove that column, or set it to an empty string. e.g.

```
function wpse_120798_item_totals($total_rows, $order) {
    foreach ($total_rows as &$row) {
        unset($row['value']); // or: $row['value'] = '';
    }
    return $total_rows;
}

add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'wpse_120798_item_totals');
});

add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', function() {
    remove_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'wpse_120798_item_totals');
});
```